# Old anime where boy has machine gun / weapon for arms

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm having trouble finding this anime/cartoon I watched back in 1998. The scene I remember was with two characters (and perhaps others in the background), where one of them slowly stabs the other in the gut with a dagger/sword, don't remember if there was blood. The art on the VHS box had a boy/kid with guns for arms and I want to say that most of the characters appeared to be modified with machine parts (androids/cyborgs). The background theme was like post-apocalypse, future, tech.

I just watched Neon Genesis Evangelion/Trigun and the art style was very similar to the anime above, but the story was not the same.

Comment: So probably not Cyborg009? (https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/Cyborg009)

Comment: Could it be the old Battle Angel Alita anime?